# Google Sheet Checkbox Formula

Tags: excel, checkbox, formula

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKjqx.png)

I am trying to create sum conditions using a checkbox with 3 columns. I am just a beginner using google sheet any inputs and help will be much appreciated.

My forumla is:  `=SUM(M2189:N2189)-L2189+I2189,SUM(O2189,I2189)`

If cell `M` and `N` is checked sum `M` and `N` - the total amount in `L cell + I` cell

Now I am getting an error on this part

`If cell O is selected it should return 0 and the value from column I.`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This pattern. And I think if you can compllete it.

```
=SUMIF(CheckboxRange,true,SumRange)
```

Comment: Hi, I will try this formula. Thank you!

Comment: @Decrie Or send a screenshot or link to your sheet. I'll solve it. It's hard for me to get the right idea.

Comment: Please have a look https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cxRvqZ8Xy4M3splIexkbFlka3Byhj4Tk001xeftAXGY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there a way to convert the currencies automatically? I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: I'll solve your problem. But the rules here do not address the issues that are not relevant to the topic. Because checkbox and money conversion are two types of problems. Submit it as a new problem. Drop me a message Your problem has been solved.

Comment: What is the value of "freight Upgade"?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot man! I will create a new thread :) happy to be part of this community

Comment: @TipsVisor Expres domestic upgrade is 9.95 AUD and Express freight international is 39.5 AUD. No upgrade is 0.00. I will keep your formula as well for reference.